# Agregar cadena aleatoria al nombre de los archivos

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy desarrollando un script en Bash que tome todas las imágenes que tengo en la carpeta y les agregue una cadena aleatoria antes de la extension. Esa cadena aleatoria sería diferente para cada fichero.

Las imágenes son algo como "01.jpg", "02.jpg"... Y la idea sería que al correr este comando se conviertan en "01-(randomstring).jpg", "02-(randomstring).jpg", etc. Ej: 01-9FbdHbpitN.jpg

- 01.jpg → 01-9FbdHbpitN.jpg

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
for f in *.jpg; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.jpg}abcd.jpg"; done
```

Pero sólo añade "abcd" al final y me gustaría poder cambiar ese "abcd" por un hash auto-generado, una cadena aleatoria cualquiera. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Quieres que ese randomstring sea el mismo para todos los archivos o cambie de uno a oro?

Comment: Que cambie de uno a otro

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for f in *.jpg; do
    random_string=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 4 | head -n 1);
    nuevo_nombre="${f%.jpg}${random_string}.jpg"
    printf "%s %s\n" "$f" "$nuevo_nombre"
done
```

Hay que hacer todas esas operaciones con pipe porque de lo contrario `dev/urandom` se mantiene generando strings para siempre.

Con este bucle *puede* ocurrir que la cadena de 4 caracteres random se repita. Pero como todas tus imágenes tienen nombres distintos, supongo que no importa mucho.

**Bonus Track** (gracias [fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui))
Cuando compruebes que la salida es la correcta, sustituye `printf` por `mv` y así cada fichero se renombrará.

Comment: ¡Interesante uso de `/dev/urandom`! Lo que haría falta es un `mv` también.

Comment: En realidad me limité a responder el uso de una cadena random. Pero reemplazar `print_r` con un `mv` es trivial, es lo mínimo que le puedo dejar de tarea al OP. Gracias por la edición.

Comment: Me imprime algunos con el random pero otros no, ademas arriba de cada uno sale ilegal bit secuence

Comment: A lo mejor depende de la distro? Yo lo acabo de hacer en Ubuntu 17.10 (me gusta jugar al límite) y funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar `uuidgen` para generar un [Identificador Único Universal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal) o UUID (por sus siglas en inglés):

```
$ ls -l *.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar 158153 Jan 26 14:28 01.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  33124 Apr 28  2016 02.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  57091 Mar 21  2017 03.jpg

$ for f in *.jpg; do echo $f; done;
01.jpg
02.jpg
03.jpg

$ for f in *.jpg; do uuid=$(uuidgen); echo "${f%.jpg}-$uuid.jpg"; done;
01-2821f254-98a3-41ac-be76-169b9a348e19.jpg
02-ace02d58-ff12-4798-93c9-eb258a80195b.jpg
03-afe5310b-e7d5-4966-a88f-432aaec4caba.jpg
```

Para moverlo finalmente usamos `mv` reemplazándolo por `echo`:

```
$ for f in *.jpg; do uuid=$(uuidgen); mv $f "${f%.jpg}-$uuid.jpg"; done;

$ ls -l *.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar 158153 Jan 26 14:28 01-2821f254-98a3-41ac-be76-169b9a348e19.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  33124 Apr 28  2016 02-ace02d58-ff12-4798-93c9-eb258a80195b.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  57091 Mar 21  2017 03-afe5310b-e7d5-4966-a88f-432aaec4caba.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
EXT=".jpg"
for f in *${EXT}; do 
   echo "${f}" "$(mktemp -u -p. $(basename ${f} ${EXT})-XXXXXX${EXT})" 
done
```

Cambia `echo` por `mv` después de experimentar un poco con el script, por ejemplo, modifica la cantidad de "X" consecutivas (sin que sea inferior a tres "XXX"). Consulta `man mktemp`.